# Run easy_install as a shell script

Tags: python, easy-install

I downloaded easy_install.  Step two is to run it as if it were a shell script, so I entered sh setuptools-0.6c9-py2.4.egg in the shell and got SyntaxError: invalid syntax back, highlighting  setuptools in red indicating that it is the invalid syntax.  I am running Python 2.7.2 on Mac OS X version 10.5.8.  What am i doing wrong???

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong! After downloading the egg file I needed to open up Terminal, NOT the python shell.  Then I needed to enter sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg into the terminal and run it by hitting enter.  For anyone else having the same problem, watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c96fTX1w_e0

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the trouble and just do this (assuming you are linux/osx)

```
wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
python ez_setup.py
```

Otherwise just download ez_setup.py manually and then run it with python as stated.